# How to remove unused styles from twitter bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

My bootstrap stylesheet size is around 120kb.

But I'm only using 25% of that stylesheet code.

I don't want that span* class. I tried it by customizing it in bootstrap [customize page](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html).

I unchecked grid system,  But I still see `span1 - span12 class` in forms, tables and responsive layouts.

Can someone help me to remove those codes?

Comment: I am not a css expert but I felt that framework like blueprint can make your life easier. They are structure only, lightweight and unlike bootstrap you can make them look different. But that's my opinion..

Comment: Simply use mixins. not the css classes

Comment: if you are already using a well established CDN version of bootstrap then you shouldn't care about those things, but if it's actually part of your build code, then you can customize it on their website or build your own using LESS and disable components you don't need - https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you more concerned about the impact of the file size on the loading time for your users? Or want to make it easier for you to read/understand the CSS if it's shorter?

Either way, I suggest you don't spend too much time worrying about removing every single extra CSS style. Uncheck the elements of Bootstrap that you don't plan on using and download the customized version. For the live/production version of your site, use a minimized version of the CSS which will further reduce the file size.

If you just want to keep the code more simple for your use, that's definitely understandable but the Bootstrap team has done a great job of organizing it. Spend a little time with it.

Consider that trying to completely remove all `span*` references will remove functionality that you might use like controlling the width of form fields. These can be very useful, even if you're not using the grid.

Comment: "Don't do that" isn't an answer, unless there's some error in doing that. You can easily save 125kb per page in CSS alone by optimizing your CSS. We may live in an age of fast data but 100kb is still 100kb, especially if your host limits data transfer per second, like many do. It's the difference between your site locking up when a bunch of people hit it at once or not.

Answer (score 36):

After an hour of struggling with grunt, I decided to try [uncss](https://github.com/giakki/uncss) by itself, and it was much simpler. If you only have a few pages to do, or don't mind doing it manually, I'd recommend doing that.

The uncss page has full instructions, but to summarize:

1. Have node.js installed.
2. `npm install -g uncss`
3. Copy the sample file from the [uncss](https://github.com/giakki/uncss) page and name it anything with a .js extension. I named it uncss.js.
4. Replace the files array with your html files. (It looks like `var files   = ['my', 'array', 'of', 'HTML', 'files']`)
5. Replace the stylesheets array with your stylesheets. (It looks like `stylesheets  : ['lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css', 'src/public/css/main.css']`). Likewise change the value of "csspath" if you need to.
6. Run `node uncss.js` (or whatever you called your uncss file).
   It spits out the optimized CSS straight to the command line, so save it to a file with something like `node uncss.js > mynewcss.css`.

There are a bunch of options to tailor the behavior. I ignored all of them and it worked fine, but they're there if you want them. The page I tested it on went from 138kb to 9kb.

Comment: This should be the answer since it directly addresses the question.

Comment: Up vote to be answer to this question. Ideal for those who are uploading CSS to Esp8266 or ESP32 Webservers. It's quite a challenge build a website to fit in 160Kb! Thanks for sharing the solution!

Answer (score 7):

I got exactly the same problem!

I wrote a tool to remove all un-used css style rules in bootstrap.css

As a result, **59% rule** has been removed, css file size reduced from **121KB to 59KB** and **increased about 5 score** when testing with [Google PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fcoupon4share.com%2F)

The source code is here [css-optimizer](https://github.com/thoqbk/css-optimizer)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that twitter bootstrap heavily relies on those `span*` classes. When I only toggle the "table" checkbox under "Base CSS", I still get `span*` classes in the compiled css, because they are rendered anyway. Take a look at https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/tables.less:

```
// R.185: Change the column widths to account for td/th padding
.table td,
.table th {
  &.span1     { .tableColumns(1); }
  &.span2     { .tableColumns(2); }
  &.span3     { .tableColumns(3); }
  &.span4     { .tableColumns(4); }
  &.span5     { .tableColumns(5); }
  &.span6     { .tableColumns(6); }
  &.span7     { .tableColumns(7); }
  &.span8     { .tableColumns(8); }
  &.span9     { .tableColumns(9); }
  &.span10    { .tableColumns(10); }
  &.span11    { .tableColumns(11); }
  &.span12    { .tableColumns(12); }
}
```

So I'm afraid you should cannot remove them with the customizer, only manually.

Answer (score 1):

I have a template using Bootstrap 2, which is the required system for Joomla. I just did this manually and found it easy to do. The Bootstrap CSS file is very nicely constructed and well ordered in sections. I removed the entire contents of the file to `bootstrap_unused.css` and then also copied that to `bootstrap_original.css`.

I then cut out from `bootstrap_unused.css` what I knew was in use, being careful to preserve the order, and pasted it back in. Most of it worked first time and reduced the file size from 144KB to 14KB. I then needed to add some bits and pieces back in for forms etc. and ended up at 30KB.

If I need any other features in the future, I can pull them back in from `bootstrap_unused.css` and I always have `bootstrap_original.css` for reference.