# How To Remove unused CSS rules

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

> **EDIT:** While my specific issue is due / relating to the Twitter Bootstrap
>   system, the solution I am looking for does not need to be Twitter
>   Bootstrap specific, but more a solution for any CSS style sheets.

I am starting to explore the world of Twitter Bootstrap for a current project I'm working on. I am using Bootstrap 3.3.6

**The Issue** *(why I have the problem below)*

The basic Bootstrap CSS file is 6760 lines, as well as additional files for adding my own custom CSS to the site. In total this gives that the site for *each page* loads ~8700 lines of CSS (unminified).

But the rules applied to the website use only ~700 of these lines. That's a **massive** overhead for each page, and even with minifying the CSS into the `.min.css` format this is still a huge percentage overhead.

I am looking for a way of reducing this overhead without removing any of the used rules from the CSS files.

**What I've tried** *(And why it didn't work or is impractical)*

I have previously used with great success the [Firefox Dust-Me](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/) CSS refiner which can identify all unused CSS rules in a page, or even on a whole site.

This is the sort of thing I want, ***but*** it has two serious drawbacks:

- It only retains CSS rules that are used on the page for the device/media that is used (so for example, it tells me that all the rules in the [IE10 viewport bug workaround](https://github.com/Haixing-Hu/bootstrap3-ie10-viewport-bug-workaround) CSS file are not used because I'm using Firefox browser rather than IE10). It also does not take into account media query specific rules.
- The other main drawback for using Dust-Me (specifically, but other similar programs I've found have a similar shortfalls) is that while it will tell me which rules are not used, it doesn't give me an ability to copy/paste the used CSS from the source files.

I have also looked into a few other CSS spare rule removers and the [Google Chrome Developers Audit](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) which is useful, but does the same thing, listing in text format the unused rules, which is barely half the job I am looking for.

**The Problem** *(Why I need your help to solve this)*

So I am in a position I have a Google Chrome Audit that tells me that 88% of `bootstrap.css` and 65% of `bootstrap-theme.css` are unused. These unused elements are listed in text format, and there are *hundreds* of them. currently I can only see that I would need to do find/replace on each one, removing them [*the rule identifiers*] from the source before then going through the CSS file and removing all the commands that no longer have any rules.

### So I am asking this:

> What is the best method or approach for me to read the CSS from a whole website, and
>   return only all the CSS rules that are referenced in the site, so rules that
>   are not referenced are not returned to the operator?

I can then take the output from this function and then minify it and save the massive CSS overhead of bootstrap.

***Or***, is there a completely different way of doing this I've not considered?

---

**Additional:** 
I have read [How to remove unused styles from twitter bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135905/how-to-remove-unused-styles-from-twitter-bootstrap) which is similar to what I'm asking, but the correct answer here references some sort of Bootstrap selection where I can choose which styles I take from the Bootstrap. This is dated 2013 and seems to refer to Bootstrap version 2.

Also, I do not use `Grunt` and am unfamiliar with `Less`.  Sorry :-/

Comment: One first step could be to build a custom version of Bootstrap without the parts you don't use: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend a technique or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: I have updated my actual question, @Paulie_D .

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: @Paulie_D Ok, how can I put the basic question "How can I remove unused (never used) CSS styles from my website style sheets?" so that it fits the SO form? Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customise the components that are compiled at http://getbootstrap.com/customize/.
This way you will have a smaller outputted file but all dependencies will be met.

To get even finer control you can use the source `.less` files to compile only the components you want.

Comment: I had not previously found this, I had only found links to the outdated boostrap2 version. I will look into this, thanks

Comment: This is really useful in *reducing* the overhead but there will still be a lot of remaining core rules in the CSS that I would ideally like to be able to remove.

Comment: Sure. It's not a perfect solution but it's a good start without having to parse all your html/css. Have you thought about downloading the source '.less' files? That way you could have even more control over what you compile

Comment: I'm not very familiar with LESS so I wasn't sure how effective it would be for me to download those files.

Comment: In that case probably would over complicate it, but if you are really concerned about the size of the file, that's your best bet. Note that bootstrap 4 will be using Sass instead of less if that helps at all

Comment: Thanks for the help, Guy. I am just about to read up on Bootstrap 4 and see if it's worth diving into that early.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [unused-css.com](https://unused-css.com/) which takes an URL as input, which is what you asked for.

Comment: This is what I am looking for but the website states it will only give the reduced files if I pay them :-(

Comment: Nevertheless it's the type of service you asked for.